# jQuery event namespaces don't work

Tags: javascript, events, namespaces, jquery

Look, it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/2pxfr/

`off` doesn't seem to unbind my event listeners :|

But without the namespace it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/2pxfr/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace needs to be preceded by a `.`

Try this:

```
 $(document).off('.myNamespace');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pxfr/2/)